# What iphone app could snooze every 5 minutes?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, alarm

I hope to find an iphone app that remind me to focus, snooze every 5 minutes, can be configured to play a ringtone or just vibrate. If the "5 minutes" is configurable, that's even better.

Unfortunately iPhone Clock alarm snoozes every 10 minutes. and "Nag" application snoozes every 1 minute :(

Comment: check this out https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-reminders-push-notifications/id382256515?mt=8

Comment: @Buscar웃 this does not snooze automatically every 5 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **[Due](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/due-reminders-countdown-timers/id390017969?mt=8)**? It’s very configurable.
This [link](https://dueapp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203299799-Reminders-not-respecting-auto-snooze-setting) shows that after a reminder is triggered you can auto-snooze the notification in as low as 5 minute intervals.